# Merge histograms with different ranges

Tags: python, numpy, merge, histogram

Is it any fast way to merge two numpy histograms with different bin ranges and bin number?

For example:

```
x = [1,2,2,3]
y = [4,5,5,6]

a = np.histogram(x, bins=10)  
#  a[0] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]
#  a[1] = [ 1. ,  1.2,  1.4,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ]

b = np.histogram(y, bins=5)
#  b[0] = [1, 0, 2, 0, 1]
#  b[1] = [ 4. ,  4.4,  4.8,  5.2,  5.6,  6. ]
```

Now I want to have some function like this:

```
def merge(a, b):
    # some actions here #
    return merged_a_b_values, merged_a_b_bins
```

Actually I have not `x` and `y`, `a` and `b` are known only. 
But the result of `merge(a, b)` must be equal to `np.histogram(x+y, bins=10)`:

```
m = merge(a, b)
#  m[0] = [1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1]
#  m[1] = [ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ,  5.5,  6. ]
```

Comment: Instead of merging two histograms why can't you use the simpler solution of combing lists and creating the histogram of it i .e., `np.histogran(x+y, bins=10)`

Comment: I don't have x and y :(

Comment: Could you write down the expected output (the actual values) for the sample?

Comment: @Reti43 But we know bins/ranges: a[1] and b[1] will hold it (a[0] and b[0] are values of histograms). We need something like resampling...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not my case. Values are floats. But we can have width constraints..

Comment: Allow me to generalise the constraint. If your floats can only take discreet values, e.g, 1.4 and 1.5 are fine, but nothing in the between, and your bin widths are smaller than the smallest difference between your floats, e.g., smaller than 0.1 for the above example, then you can reconstruct your initial vectors. If you can't ensure these conditions, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes, I think we can use minimal distance between values is equal to 0.01.

Comment: What matters is that the histograms are created with the necessary number of bins to achieve this width. For example, for a list `x = [4.38, 5.26, 5.27]`, you require at least `np.round((max(x) - min(x)) / 0.01) + 1` bins, i.e., 90 bins, to ensure your list can be reconstructed. If you can have this control over the histogram generation, even though you can't save the values of `x` and `y`, you can still retrieve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unique solution to the problem of merging two different histograms. I propose here a simple and quick solution based on two design assumptions necessary to deal with the loss of information inherent from binning sequences:

1. Recovered values are represented by the start of the bin they belong to.
2. The merge shall keep the highest bin resolution to avoid further loss of information and shall completely encompass the intervals of the children histograms.

Here's the code:

```
  import numpy as np

  def merge(a, b):

      def extract_vals(hist):
          # Recover values based on assumption 1.
          values = [[y]*x for x, y in zip(hist[0], hist[1])]
          # Return flattened list.
          return [z for s in values for z in s]

      def extract_bin_resolution(hist):
          return hist[1][1] - hist[1][0]

      def generate_num_bins(minval, maxval, bin_resolution):
          # Generate number of bins necessary to satisfy assumption 2
          return int(np.ceil((maxval - minval) / bin_resolution))

      vals = extract_vals(a) + extract_vals(b)
      bin_resolution = min(map(extract_bin_resolution, [a, b]))
      num_bins = generate_num_bins(min(vals), max(vals), bin_resolution)

      return np.histogram(vals, bins=num_bins)
```

Here's the example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,2,3]
y = [4,5,5,6]

a = np.histogram(x, bins=10)  
#  a[0] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]
#  a[1] = [ 1. ,  1.2,  1.4,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ]

b = np.histogram(y, bins=5)
#  b[0] = [1, 0, 2, 0, 1]
#  b[1] = [ 4. ,  4.4,  4.8,  5.2,  5.6,  6. ]

# Merge and plot results
c = merge(a, b)

c_num_bins = c[1].size - 1

plt.hist(a[0], bins=5, label='a')
plt.hist(b[0], bins=10, label='b')
plt.hist(c[0], bins=c_num_bins, label='c')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd actually have added a comment to dangom's answer, but I lack the reputation required.
I'm a little confused by your example. You're plotting the histogram of the histogram bins if I'm not mistaken. It should rather be this, right?

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(a[1][:-1], a[0], marker='.', label='a')
plt.plot(b[1][:-1], b[0], marker='.', label='b')
plt.plot(c[1][:-1], c[0], marker='.', label='c')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Also a note to your suggestion for combining the histogram. You are of course right, that there's no unique solution as you simply don't know, where the samples would've have been in the finer grid you use for the combination. When having two histograms, which have a significantly differing bin width the suggested merging function may result in a sparse and artificial looking histogram.

I tried combining the histograms by interpolation (assuming the samples within the count bin were distributed uniformly in the original bin - which is of course also only an assumption).
This leads however to a more natural looking result, at least for data sampled from distributions I typically encounter.

```
import numpy as np
def merge_hist(a, b):

    edgesa = a[1]
    edgesb = b[1]
    da = edgesa[1]-edgesa[0]
    db = edgesb[1]-edgesb[0]
    dint = np.min([da, db])

    min = np.min(np.hstack([edgesa, edgesb]))
    max = np.max(np.hstack([edgesa, edgesb]))
    edgesc = np.arange(min, max, dint)

    def interpolate_hist(edgesint, edges, hist):
        cumhist = np.hstack([0, np.cumsum(hist)])
        cumhistint = np.interp(edgesint, edges, cumhist)
        histint = np.diff(cumhistint)
        return histint

    histaint = interpolate_hist(edgesc, edgesa, a[0])
    histbint = interpolate_hist(edgesc, edgesb, b[0])

    c = histaint + histbint
    return c, edgesc
```

An example for two gaussian distributions:

```
import numpy as np
a = 5 + 1*np.random.randn(100)
b = 10 + 2*np.random.randn(100)
hista, edgesa = np.histogram(a, bins=10)
histb, edgesb = np.histogram(b, bins=5)

histc, edgesc = merge_hist([hista, edgesa], [histb, edgesb])

plt.figure()
width = edgesa[1]-edgesa[0]
plt.bar(edgesa[:-1], hista, width=width)
width = edgesb[1]-edgesb[0]
plt.bar(edgesb[:-1], histb, width=width)
plt.figure()
width = edgesc[1]-edgesc[0]
plt.bar(edgesc[:-1], histc, width=width)

plt.show()
```

I, however, am no statistician, so please let me know if the suggestes approach is viable.